# Scroll Slowly and Automatically to the end of RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, richtextbox

I am making an application where I have to put certain warnings in RichTextBox. The goal is to make it slow down automatically so that the user could read the warning. I already research on automatically scroll to the end, but what I want is to scroll slowly descend until the end of the richtextbox.

this is my code

```
foreach (var item in MyService.GetAviso()) 
{
  RTB_Avisos.Text = RTB_Avisos.Text + item.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
  if (aux_Avisos == 2)
  {
    RTB_Avisos.Text = RTB_Avisos.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    aux_Avisos = 0;
  }
  else
   aux_Avisos++;

  RTB_Avisos.SelectionStart = RTB_Avisos.Text.Length;
  RTB_Avisos.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

I have the

```
RTB_Avisos.SelectionStart = RTB_Avisos.Text.Length;
RTB_Avisos.ScrollToCaret();
```

but I want get the scroll constantly and not instantly.

**ANSWER**

After a long time searching, i find the answer, its not the best way to do that, but its a solution. You can create a **timer** , and when he `tick` you put that code:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        order = linePos == RTB_Avisos.Lines.Length - 1 ? -1 : linePos == 0 ? 1 : order;

        linePos += order;

        int offset = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < linePos && i < RTB_Avisos.Lines.Length; i++)
            offset += RTB_Avisos.Lines[i].Length + 1;

        RTB_Avisos.Focus();
        RTB_Avisos.Select(offset, 0);
    }
```

This code will count the lines, and slow down with a determinated interval of time. When we get the last line of RTB, the go back to the beginning.

Ty for help...

Comment: Its difficult to help you when we have no basis for where you are with your application.  Please post code that shows what you've got so far, what you've tried and what errors have occurred and it will make it much easier to help.

Comment: you get my code. If you know resolve the problem, tell me, pls :)

Comment: These examples are in VB, but should work for you. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?629400-Smooth-scrolling-rich-text-box-with-timer